# Trouble unzipping documents parser

Tags: r, parsing

I am trying to do a simple task: to unzip a lot a of text documents.

Here is what I have:

```
parser <- ArgumentParser()
parser$add_argument("--input",
                    default = paste0(root_dir, "/import/input/informes.zip"))
parser$add_argument("--output=", 
                    default = paste0(root_dir, "/import/output/df_inf_pre.csv.gz"))
args <- parser$parse_args()
```

but when I run:

```
df_zip_files <- unzip(args$input, list=TRUE)
```

I get this error:

Error in unzip(args$input, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file '/Users/myname/directoy/informes.zip' cannot be opened

Comment: Yes. The content is fine.

Comment: Does `file.exists(args$input)` return true? It just sounds like you are passing in an incorrect path.